# What is the best replacement of normal?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, american-english

The Armstrong limit, often called Armstrong's line, is a level of altitude in which water boils at 37C, normal body temperature. 
Here is the question: 
Which one of the following best replaces "normal" while maintaining the meaning of the sentence (resting - typical - traditional - regulars)?

Comment: What are your own thoughts about this so far?

Comment: For my opinion, resting is best option of yours. I would use "avareage ... temperature" phrase.

Comment: @hkulekci why not typical?

Comment: You should review the definitions of each word and consider how they apply to the example. Then adding additional details to your question makes for a better explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*normal body temperature* is the usual way this phrase is used. But if you have to choose, then "typical", which has a similar meaning, is OK.

Not *resting* because we don't know if resting is a criteria.

Not *traditional*, because this has a completely different meaning.

*regular* is far too broad in meaning to be usable in your example.